# Cannot access non-static method (constructor) from main (tried instantiating)

Tags: java, constructor, static, non-static

I've had a thorough search already and I know that you have to instantiate an object first inside the static method main () before you can access its non-static variable or method.
However, I believe I have done  this so I cannot understand the problem of getting the "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context" here.

I am just starting out trying to learn java, but shouldn't this basic constructor work?

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        A outer = new A(); //<-- Error here
    }

    class A 
    {      
        A()
        {
            System.out.println("I'm from outer class A");
        }
    }
}
```

It will instantiate class A if I declare it static, but I shouldn't need to do this as I've created the object. It also does not work if I have just an empty constructor.

If someone could help I would be very grateful. I know it's a ridiculously simple error but I have been searching for hours on it and cannot figure it out.

Comment: What you have here is an inner class. An inner class requires an instance of the enclosing class (Main in your case).

Comment: to make it more clear what @Eran is saying, try changing the class you are using in the `main` method to represent a `Main` instead of an `A` and see what happens.

Comment: Make `A` static... (`static class A {}`)

Comment: And don't describe it as 'outer' when it isn't.

Comment: @davidxx It certainly does. Try it before you dig any deeper.

Comment: @EJB You are totally right. Bad habit to read and register in my head eclipse error message that is not the same as which one of javac : "No enclosing instance of type xxx is accessible." Which finally is just a more specific message.

Answer (score 0):

I see what happened now.
I made the "A" class inside Main, which was an error - it was supposed to be outside. In other words, I missed a bracket.

I was following a tutorial about nested classes (class "B" was inside "A" but I removed it for the purposes of this post).

It was a silly error, thanks for the patience.